# How to show multiple pages in Print Preview Dialog?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I just want ask what's wrong with my code? It is not proceeding in the next page it`s just overlapping in the current page.

```
Private Sub PD_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PD.PrintPage
    Try
        Dim font As New Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim font2 As New Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim count As Integer
        count = dgDailyReport.RowCount - 1
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim Date_Saved As String
        Dim Total_Income As String
        Dim Location As Integer = 50
        Dim Location2 As Integer = 180
        Dim Location3 As Integer = 250

        While i <= count
            Date_Saved = dgDailyReport.Item("Date", i).Value.ToString
            Total_Income = dgDailyReport.Item("Total_Income", i).Value.ToString

            e.Graphics.DrawString("BPC-FASA", font, Brushes.Black, 50, 50)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Bulihan City of Malolos, Bulacan", font, Brushes.Black, 50,70)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("CONTRIBUTION DAILY REPORT", font2, Brushes.Black, 50, 90)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Date", font, Brushes.Black, 50, 150)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Date_Saved, font, Brushes.Black, Location, Location2)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Income", font, Brushes.Black, 250, 150)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("₱ " + Total_Income, font, Brushes.Black, Location3, Location2)
            i += 1
            Location2 += 25

            If Location2 >= 1100 Then
                Location = 180
                e.HasMorePages = True
            Else
                e.HasMorePages = False
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is The print button

```
 Private Sub cmdPrint_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrint.Click
      Dim csz As New System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400)
      PD.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = csz
      PPD.ShowDialog()
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it.  Where in that code are you exiting that `While` loop?  Nowhere, other than when you get to the end of the records.  You need to exit the loop when you get to either the end of the records or the end of the page.  It is at that point that you need to decide whether there are more pages to print and set `HasMorePages`.  If there are more pages, you also need to remember what record you were up to, so you can start there rather than at the first one again.  The `PrintPage` event handler is for printing one page, so you need to:

1. Determine what page you're up to.
2. Print the data for that page.
3. Determine whether there are more pages to print.